# WordPress inserting ?q= in URLs

Tags: urls

When I try to switch from editing a page or post to the actual post, WordPress inserts "?q=" after the root URL (and changes slashes to "%2F"). I've not seen this before, and Google is not pulling up any suggestions. Does anyone know what might cause this and how I can revert?

Comment: q isn't one of the [standard query vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars). Any chance your theme is doing this, e.g. if you're using a single page theme?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you don't have q as parameter in your permalink settings. You can see the permalink settings from `wp-admin -> settings -> permalinks`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same thing happening with mine too... trying to investigate where it's coming from but nothing yet.   nothing in permalink settings, maybe something with a plugin is my guess.   happens if i use the root domain, but not on www, so also maybe something with a weird 301/302 redirect somewhere uproute.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/242116)